# Struggling to multiply a number from a text file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a piece of code for a till roll. I am struggling to take the price in the text file and multiplying it by the quantity entered by the user. I'm not sure how to solve.

This is what I have done so far;

**Part of code too, below**

```
def receipt():
    food = input("Enter the product code for the item you want.")

    fi = open("data.txt","r")
    info = fi.readlines()
    fi.close()
    item = False 
    for li in info:
        if(li.split(":")[0].lower() == food):
            print(li.split(":")[1])
            item = True
            quantity = input("How many do you want?")        
            print("£" + quantity)
receipt()
```

The text file:

```
12345670:Burgers, £1:1.30   
19203123:Cheese, £2.50:2.50
98981236:Crisps, 0.55p:0.55
56756777:Alphabetti Spaghetti, £1.45:1.45
90673412:Sausages, £2.30:2.30
84734952:Lemonade, 0.99p:0.99
18979832:Ice Cream, £1.50:1.50
45353456:6 Pack of Beer, £5:5.00
98374500:Gum, 0.35p:0.35 
85739011:Apples, 0.70p:0.70
```

I think I have to use .append or lists but I don't know how they work as I haven't learnt them yet.

Comment: What's the trouble? What's the error? What's the expected output?

Comment: Why is the price two times in each line?

Comment: Where is your code that tries to do the multiplication? How are we supposed to show you what you're doing wrong if you don't post the code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the price from the line in the file and convert it into a floating point number:

```
price = float(li.split(":")[2])
```

Will give you the price of the item on a given line. This converts the price at the end of the line to a float, or decimal number, and then you can use it how you please.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total price, you need to take the quantity the user entered and convert it to an integer (float does not really make sense). You can get the price with `li.rsplit(':',1)[-1]`. Don't forget to convert it to a float.

Demo:

```
>>> quantity = int(input('how many do you want? ')) # make int out of input string
how many do you want? 10
>>> li = '90673412:Sausages, £2.30:2.30' # example line
>>> quantity * float(li.rsplit(':', 1)[-1])
23.0
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating the for loop like so to split the lines into their respective parts, then you can manipulate the parts as you need to like `id.lower()` and `float(price)`

```
for li in info:
    id,desc,price = li.split(':')
    if id.lower() == food:
        item = True
        quantity = int(input("How many do you want? "))
        print("£" + str(quantity*float(price)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Wolf :Please try the below code, It should work. Since the data retrieved from
 txt file is in ASCII format the if condition seems to be failing.

```
import chardet

def receipt():
    food = input("Enter the product code for the item you want.")
    fi = open("data.txt","r")
    info = fi.readlines()
    fi.close()
    item = False
    for li in info:
        a = li.split(":")[0].lower()
        encoding = chardet.detect(a)
        #print encoding
        #int(a) 
        #print int(a)
        if int(a) == food:
            #print "pass"
            print(li.split(":")[1])
            #print item
            item = True
            quantity = input("How many do you want?")
            print( quantity)
receipt()
```

Comment: I tried this however it did not work, it told me that there is 'no module named chardet'

Comment: @Wolf : chardet is a pip package, try downloading it.